# Using "totals" functions on an already grouped query

Tags: ms-access

I am having troubles using the aggregate functions when using features like `group by` in a query. Instead of my aggregate functions applying to the entire query recordset, they only apply to select groups determined by the nature of the query. For example:

```
  Person      Date      Able
 -----------------------------
    A       21/05/13     0
    B       21/05/13    -1
    C       21/05/13    -1
    D       21/05/13     0

(grouped by Person, Date, Able)
```

When applying aggregate functions:

```
 Person      Date      Able    Max(Able)   Min(Date)
----------------------------------------------------
   A       21/05/13     0          0       21/05/13  
   B       22/05/13    -1         -1       22/05/13
   C       23/05/13    -1         -1       23/05/13
   D       24/05/13     0          0       24/05/13
```

The aggregate functions are made entirely redundant unless the data is completely ungrouped. So far, I have been getting around it using:

1) Using another query to reference the initial query and determine the true aggregate values.
2) Have the form call this second query using the `d` functions (`dlookup`,`dcount` etc.)

In my particular scenario, I have a list (very similar to above) that needs to be presented in a certain order (ranked based on ID). However, I am using an expression in the query to define a different type of ranking. The idea is to show (using conditional formatting) the first record in this new rank. Illustrated below

```
 Person      Date      ID   CalculatedRank    
--------------------------------------------
   A       21/05/13     1        4
   B       21/05/13     2        2
   C       21/05/13     3        3
   D       21/05/13     4        1
```

Ideally I would like to have another column that determines which one is first which could be easily acheived by:

```
first: [CalculatedRank] = Min( [CalculatedRank] )
```

But as described above, Min() is not giving me 1, it is giving me it on a per row basis (the minimimum isn't always 1 so I can't set this arbitrarily).

Right now I am using a separate query to reference this first query and I sort that based on the calculated rank. Conditional formatting can then use dlookup to determine whether it is first or not from the second query. However, everytime the form refreshes, or a requery is called, every single row's conditional formatting triggers another dlookup, which then references the first query recalculating the new rank, for every row!

As you can imagine, the delay is noticeable causing the cursor to be idle for >5seconds. I am not too sure about the internal mechanisms of access, but using the inbuilt debugger, a requery on a recordset of 4 rows caused my `CalculateRank()` function to be called 12 times, purely through the conditional formatting calling the second query.

In summary, I have pretty much narrowed it down to requiring a separate query (and therefore dlookup) to properly use the aggregate functions. If I was able to keep everything in one query, the conditional formatting wouldn't need to use dlookup on another query to determine its status.

I am sure I am not the only one that has had problems with this and was wondering if any solutions exist where I can avoid all the stacked querying.

As always, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I see what you mean! For my table [Table1]

```
Person  Date        ID
------  ----------  --
A       2013-05-21   1
B       2013-05-21   2
C       2013-05-21   3
D       2013-05-21   4
```

and my query [qryTable1Ranked]

```
SELECT Table1.*, CalculateRank([ID]) AS CalculatedRank
FROM Table1;
```

which uses the following function in a standard VBA Module

```
Public Function CalculateRank(ID As Long) As Long
Dim r As Long
Select Case ID
    Case 1
        r = 4
    Case 4
        r = 1
    Case Else
        r = ID
End Select
CalculateRank = r
Debug.Print "x"
End Function
```

and returns

```
Person  Date        ID  CalculatedRank
------  ----------  --  --------------
A       2013-05-21   1               4
B       2013-05-21   2               2
C       2013-05-21   3               3
D       2013-05-21   4               1
```

when I just double-click the query to open it in Datasheet View my ranking function gets called 4 times, once for each row.

If I create a continuous form based on that query and open the form my function gets called 4 times. Then if I add conditional formatting on the [CalculatedRank] text box using `Value = DMin("CalculatedRank", "qryTable1Ranked")` then my function gets called 32 times!

I found that I can cut that by half (to 16 times) if I add an invisible unbound textbox named [txtMinCalculatedRank], use the following code behind the form...

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
UpdateMinCalculatedRank
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMinCalculatedRank()
Me.txtMinCalculatedRank.Value = DMin("CalculatedRank", "qryTable1Ranked")
End Sub
```

...and change the Conditional Formatting rule to `Value = [txtMinCalculatedRank]`.

I found that I could cut that by half again (to 8 times) if I changed the `Record Source` of the Form from `qryTable1Ranked` to `Table1` (the base table) and changed the `Control Source` of the [CalculatedRank] text box to `=CalculateRank([ID])` (still using the tricks from the previous tweak).

I *think* that's probably as good as it gets without going so far as to create a temporary table, or persisting the CalculatedRank (and perhaps an "IsMin" flag) in the base table.

Comment: Gord, sorry for the late reply. I was hoping to take some time to see if I could use your tricks and some I already had in place to reduce it further but I wasn't successful. I wish there was some sort of call stack that was visible so I could determine when and why conditional formatting seems to requery so many times. I guess it's something that may have to be addressed in a future version of access. Thanks again for your effort and input.